# How to add scrollbar for UIComponent in flex4.0 after it zoom

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, canvas, flash-builder, zooming

I am using a canvas with UIComponent for loading image in flex4. I want to zoom image, it is done image is zoomed but scrollbar is not added to canvas because i want to move image with scrolling and also mouse over, Please suggest me any solution for this or any having application.
Thanks,
Nitin

---

### LoadPDF.mxml

```
<mx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="PDFComplete",type="flash.events.Event")]
</mx:Metadata>

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        private var swfURL:String = "pdf/outra.swf";
        public var loader:Loader = null;

        public var bool:Boolean = false;
        public var myPath:String = "";

        import mx.events.ScrollEvent;

        public var libMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        private function init():void {

            /*Hide the default context menu with print option*/
            var myMenu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
            myMenu.hideBuiltInItems();
            var defaultItems:ContextMenuBuiltInItems = myMenu.builtInItems;
            defaultItems.print = false;
            this.contextMenu = myMenu;

            //if (ExternalInterface.available)
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("pdfURL", loadPDF);

            if(bool == false) {
                loadPDF(swfURL);
                bool = true;
            }
        }

        private function loadPDF(name:String):void {

            myPath = name;
            if(loader!= null) {
                swfContainer.removeChild(loader);
                loader = null;
            }

            loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfComplete);
            var fLoader:ForcibleLoader = new ForcibleLoader(loader);
            fLoader.load(new URLRequest(myPath));
            swfContainer.addChild(loader);
            swfContainer.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, updateStageSize);
        }

        private function swfComplete(event:Event):void{
            libMC = event.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
            libMC.gotoAndStop(1);
            dispatchEvent(new Event("PDFComplete"));
            controls.target = libMC;
            controls.rootSwfContainer = swfContainer;

            libMC.x = (swfContainer.width/2)-(libMC.width/2);
            libMC.y = (swfContainer.height/2)-(libMC.height/2);

            var point:Point=new Point(libMC.x+libMC.width/2, libMC.y+libMC.height/2);
            controls.points = point;    
        }

        public function updateStageSize(e:Event):void
        {
            if(libMC.width < swfContainer.width && libMC.height < swfContainer.height) {                    
                libMC.x = (swfContainer.width-libMC.width)/2;
                libMC.y = (swfContainer.height-libMC.height)/2;
            }
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>


<views:Control id="controls"/>
<mx:HDividedBox top="40" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:Canvas id="canvasContainer" backgroundColor="#222222" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="auto" verticalScrollPolicy="auto">
        <mx:UIComponent id="swfContainer" width="100%" height="100%"/>          

    </mx:Canvas>            
</mx:HDividedBox>
```

---

### Control.mxml

```
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.DropdownEvent;
        import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;

        [Bindable]private var _currentPage:Number;
        private var _target:*;
        private var _swfContainer:*;
        private var _point:Point;
        private var currentScale:Number =1;
        private var rotateIndex:Number = 0;

        public function set target(value:*):void {
            _target = value;
        }
        public function get target():*{
            return _target;
        }

        public function set rootSwfContainer(value:*):void {
            _swfContainer = value;
        }

        public function get rootSwfContainer():* {
            return _swfContainer;
        }

        public function set points(point:Point):* {
            _point = point;
        }

        public function get points():* {
            return _point;
        }

        public function zoomIN():void {

            if((Number(_target.width - _swfContainer.width) <= 1000 ) || (Number(_target.height - _swfContainer.height ) <= 1000)) {
                var xPos:Number =  (_swfContainer.width/2)-(_target.width/2);
                var yPos:Number =  (_swfContainer.height/2)-(_target.height/2);

                Tweener.addTween(_target, {x:xPos, y:yPos, scaleX: _target.scaleX * 1.25, scaleY: _target.scaleY * 1.25, transition: 'easeOut'});

                repositionObject();
            }
        }


        public function zoomOUT():void {

            if((_target.width > 100) && (_target.height > 100)) {

                var xPos:Number =  (_swfContainer.width/2)-(_target.width/2);
                var yPos:Number =  (_swfContainer.height/2)-(_target.height/2);

                Tweener.addTween(_target, {x:xPos, y:yPos,scaleX: _target.scaleX * .6, scaleY: _target.scaleY * .6, transition: 'easeOut'});

                repositionObject();
            }   
        }

        public function repositionObject():void {

            var tempXPos:Number = Number((_swfContainer.width/2)-(_target.width/2));
            var tempYPos:Number = Number((_swfContainer.height/2)-(_target.height/2));


                if(tempXPos <= 0) {
                    tempXPos = 0;
                } 

                if(tempYPos <= 0) {
                    tempYPos = 0;                       
                } 
                _target.x = tempXPos;
                _target.y = tempYPos;
        }       


    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<!-- icon="@Embed(source='assets/buttonicon.png')" height="16"-->
<mx:Button label="Zoom In (+)"  click="zoomIN()" />
<mx:Button label="Zoom Out (-)" click="zoomOUT()"/>
```

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: LoadPDF.mxml
---------------

Comment: Hi, I added code of application. When zoomin button is pressed, It is zoomed with adding scrollbar, Plz help me.